# Azure SQL Data Warehouse equivalent of AWS Redshift's "UNLOAD" statement

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, amazon-redshift, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

Is there any command in Azure SQL Database/Data warehouse, that is similar to UNLOAD statement in Redshift?

I am looking for a sql statement in Azure that will create a file in Azure blob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT.

[From the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-as-select-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [ [database_name  . [ schema_name ] . ] | schema_name . ] table_name   
    WITH (   
        LOCATION = 'hdfs_folder',  
        DATA_SOURCE = external_data_source_name,  
        FILE_FORMAT = external_file_format_name  
        [ , <reject_options> [ ,...n ] ]  
    )  
    AS <select_statement>  
[;]  

<reject_options> ::=  
{  
    | REJECT_TYPE = value | percentage  
    | REJECT_VALUE = reject_value  
    | REJECT_SAMPLE_VALUE = reject_sample_value  
}  

<select_statement> ::=  
    [ WITH <common_table_expression> [ ,...n ] ]  
    SELECT <select_criteria>
```

Comment: In Azure DW I thought you had to do CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT for export rather than an INSERT?

Comment: You are so right, I was a bit hasty. Corrected and apologies!